# Pygame equivalent for Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I was wondering if anyone knew of a PyGame equivalent for Ruby. I've seen Ruby/SDL and I'm looking for something a little more geared towards games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/rubygame/

edit:
Indeed, the link has changed: http://rubygame.sourceforge.net/
(as radioact1ve mentioned)

Answer (score 6):

There's also [gosu](http://www.libgosu.org/) which might be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

http://rubygame.sourceforge.net/

edit: to slow...

Answer (score 2):

yes gosu is a great library, check it out here: http://www.libgosu.org/